# android login beginner class

Tags: java, android

i am learning android.. well i added the code here catchmayuri.blogspot.in/2010/12/sample-android-login-application.html anways wen i implemeted the code the app is not running...

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login5"
    />
```

this is the code of xml
and the folowing is the code in mainAcivity.java

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    unameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    passEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    System.out.println("button login obtaied");
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            user = unameEdit.getText().toString().trim();
            pass = passEdit.getText().toString().trim();
            if (user.equalsIgnoreCase(pass)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successfull",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // setContentView(R.layout.secondpage); Call Intent

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondClass.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Check the Username/password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

the apk file dosent run... what am i doing wrong here????

Comment: What error is coming when you run your project..

Comment: emulator says the  app failed to start.. log cat  is blank

Answer (score 3):

You got `ClassCastExeption` at `loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);`.

Try this

```
   loginButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
```

Comment: BlackTiger, I did that but the apk file still wont run.. ie the emulator is saying myfirstapp failed to start

Comment: well the error turned out to be the intent.. if i hide it the emulator has no problem working...

Comment: have you define `SecondClass` Activity in Manifest file ??

Comment: yea that was the problem..  thanks balck tiger.. btw.. can we declare an asnctask for a jason parser??

Comment: Refer this [android-asynctask-json-parsing-example](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-asynctask-json-parsing-example.html)